# Substances comprised of large molecules are liquids at room temperature?

Tags: molecules, materials, surface-chemistry

I am looking for compounds that are liquid at normal temperatures and are physically very large, to be used in an ellipsometer adsorption experiment. I am currently working with decane. The candidates will ideally not be toxic or radioactive (such as $\ce{UF6}$).

Comment: What about solutions of proteins? Human serum albumin or something even larger?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Must be a pure liquid for use in vacuum with no secondary components

Comment: Maybe someone can comment on the suitability of a room temp. ionic liquid?

Comment: You need a molecule with weak intermolecular forces and low symmetry.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydimethylsiloxane ?

Comment: Dirk - what are you looking for the molecule to do in your experiment? Provide the largest change per molecule in psi and delta, or what? Presumably a visible ellipsometer, not IR or UV?

Comment: Look for liquid crystal molecules, many are large, for example those based on porphyrins.

Answer (score 5):

You may give porphyrins a try.  These dyes are of interest for molecular electronics, and to render them less crystalline / more glassy, alkyl chains are attached to the central motif.  One recent example are the room temperature liquid porphyrins developed in the group around professor Gryko:

[image]

([source](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/asia.200900693/abstract), *Chem Asian J.* 2010, 5, 904-909; doi: 10.1002/asia.200900693.)

Besides standard spectroscopic characterisation, the publication contains the results of DSC:

[image]

so compound **4d** ($\ce{C176H294N4O12}$) may be a good candidate for an organic molecule, without charges and metal coordination, and suitable for ellipsometry / VASE measurments on surfaces.